# MonacaでAndroidの画面の向きを設定する方法

Tags: android, monaca

MonacaでAndroidアプリを開発中ですが
画面の向きの設定方法が解らずにいます。

ネットで調べたところ
`AndroidManifest.xml`の`activity`に`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`を足せば制御出来るらしいですが出来ません。
Android 4.4.4では動かないものなのでしょうか？

ご教示お願いします。

Comment: 画面を「landscape（横長）に固定したい」ということでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。
横：landscape
縦：portrait
どちらを設定しても効いてないようです。
android:configChanges=“orientation"
を設定してみてもダメでした。

Answer (score 1):

Androidの場合、`config.xml`内にある

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="default"/>
```

の`value`を、縦なら`portrait`、横なら`landscape`に設定します。

11/10 追記
MonacaクラウドIDEから`設定`→`Androidアプリ設定`と選択し、一番下までスクロールすると`画面の向き`という項目があります。
そこで向きを選択して保存すると、`config.xml`内の上記項目が書き換わります。

Comment: 出来ました！！！
なんとお礼を言っていいのかありがとうございます。